# Difference in PInvoke GetMonitorInfo between WPF and Console Application

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application, pinvoke

I am working on an application (WPF) that gets monitor information for all attached displays. To do a little unit testing, quick results, I spun up a console application project in the same solution. Here is the code that I use to get MonitorInfo (called the exact same way by both projects, and the code is located in a class library).

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hmon, ref MonitorInfo mi);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lprcClip, MonitorEnumDelegate lpfnEnum, IntPtr dwData);

public DisplayInfoCollection GetDisplays()
    {
        DisplayInfoCollection col = new DisplayInfoCollection();

        EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
            delegate(IntPtr hMonitor, IntPtr hdcMonitor, ref Rect lprcMonitor, IntPtr dwData)
            {
                MonitorInfo mi = new MonitorInfo();
                mi.size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(mi);
                bool success = GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, ref mi);

                if (success)
                {
                    DisplayInfo di = new DisplayInfo();
                    di.ScreenWidth = (mi.monitor.right - mi.monitor.left);
                    di.ScreenHeight = (mi.monitor.bottom - mi.monitor.top);
                    di.MonitorArea = new Rectangle(mi.monitor.left, mi.monitor.top, di.ScreenWidth, di.ScreenHeight);
                    di.Availability = mi.flags.ToString();
                    col.Add(di);
                }
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);
        return col;
    }
```

I noticed that the output of the monitor dimensions for my laptop screen (I have a laptop, and a secondary display) is different between the WPF and Console App.

> Laptop Resolution

- WPF - 1920x1080
- Console Application - 1536x864

The resolution that I have through my Display-->Screen Resolution settings is the same as the WPF resolution. I imagine that this is something to do with DPI, but I am confused why this is the case? I have not set any DPI awareness on either application. Are WPF apps by default DPI aware to some extent? If not, what can I do to get the output the same no matter what the consumer is?

Comment: This is third time you asked a question about this topic, why isn't this going anywhere?

Comment: It is going somewhere, as I have made huge strides with my WPF app. This is more a question about how things work than asking for help. I have learned alot about PInvoke and how you can get Display info that way. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: It should be obvious from your previous questions that, yes, it is DPI awareness.  A WPF app automatically calls SetProcessDPIAware() when it starts up, a console mode app does not.